# Grub rescue problem after deleting UBUNTU 16.04 partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, grubrescue

I am a user of HP pavilion G6- 2230TX. In this system I had dual booting option. First one was UBUNTU 16.04 and the 2nd one was windows 10. But I use mainly UBUNTU operating system. But before some time when I start my computer I faced a booting problem, which I could not solve. So, I entered in the WINDOWS operating system and deleted the UBUNTU partition from the disk. After that I restart my computer but it is showing **GRUB RESCUE>**. I can not understand how to get access to my computer. There are several important documents in my laptop, which I do not want to harm. I can access my BIOS, but from there I can not do any thing. Can someone please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: were you planning to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, and also want to keep the WINDOWS .

Comment: You may want to use some kind of windows recovery to get your documents and backup first, but all you have to do in theory is boot Ubuntu installation media and install Ubuntu alongside Windows - all being well it will install a shiny new GRUB which will boot your Windows too. You may need [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](//askubuntu.com/q/343268)...

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and come back to you about the results.